# What is this network pattern/symbol called

Tags: background

So I want to make a seamless repeating background pattern using the line and dot in this image below...

Is there a name for this type of design?

(sidenote) If you have any other suggestions, I'm trying to convey a corporate feel to big social media data. I'll submit a nice grayscale/monochrome image to a design blog or subtlepatterns or something once it's done. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Network diagram** is the most common term I know. I've also heard them referred to as **node maps**.